# Android: Starting via Share-Dialog and normally

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I try to code an app, which can receive images from gallery via Share Dialog and can be started normally
I have an Activity with is opening by Share Dialog to receive Images.
For this issue, I have following code:

```
if (!getIntent().getExtras()==(null))
Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Now I want to start this Activity also normally. It works.
But is this good practice to check if Extra_Stream is null or not null to check how the activity was started?
And how can I check more specify? I mean other Types of Extras can be involved. So a key would be helpful. But I don´t know how, because I realized that in the Manifest.

To Enable Share-Dialog I have following in the Manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".Setup" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check value of the action.

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    // code specific for ACTION_SEND
}
```

Comment: If I start normally the getIntent().getAction() gives me "Main" and via Share-Dialog null